# 2 containers aligned vertically in horizontal line with the other 2 containers

Tags: html, css

Okay so I want to put 2 vertical containers in horizontal line with other 2 containers in css and want to make it responsive.
This is a visual example what I want to do:
[image]

Can somebody put an example how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using `flex`.

```css
.top,
.bottom,
.middle,
.right {
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  height: 200px;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left, 
.middle,
.right {
  width: calc(100%/3);
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```